# How to randomly select from a json file?

Tags: python, json

I would like to select a song name and artist using their Id numbers, from an external `json` file, randomly:

```
[
 {
   "id": 1,
   "Song1": {
      "Song_nam": "killer queen"
   },
   "Song_artist": "queen"
},
 {
   "id": 2,
   "Song1": {
      "Song_nam": "Africa"
   },
   "Song_artist": "Toro"
},
 {
   "id": 3,
   "Song1": {
      "Song_nam": "Perfect"
   },
   "Song_artist": "Ed sheeran"
}
]
```

Comment: If you import the json with the json module, you get a list. You can then use random.choice() to pick a random item from that list.

Comment: What are you asking, how to read a JSON file, or how to pick a random item from a collection?

Answer (score 1):

Use `random.choice()`

```
import random

songs = [
 {
   "id": 1,
   "Song1": {
      "Song_nam": "killer queen"
   },
   "Song_artist": "queen"
},
 {
   "id": 2,
   "Song1": {
      "Song_nam": "Africa"
   },
   "Song_artist": "Toro"
},
 {
   "id": 3,
   "Song1": {
      "Song_nam": "Perfect"
   },
   "Song_artist": "Ed sheeran"
}
]

song = random.choice(songs)
print(f"Name: {song['Song1']['Song_nam']}, Artist: {song['Song_artist']}")
```

Answer (score 1):

***"songs.json"* content:**

```
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "Song1": {
    "Song_nam": "killer queen"
  },
  "Song_artist": "queen"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "Song1": {
    "Song_nam": "Africa"
  },
  "Song_artist": "Toro"
}, 
{
  "id": 3,
  "Song1": {
    "Song_nam": "Perfect"
  },
  "Song_artist": "Ed sheeran"
}
]
```

**Code:**

```
import json
from random import choice

with open("songs.json") as f:
    content = json.loads(f.read())

winner = choice(content)

print(json.dumps(winner, indent=4))
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "Song1": {
        "Song_nam": "Africa"
    },
    "Song_artist": "Toro"
}
```